# jQuery click function and Callback Arrays

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I`m new to jQuery and have a problem understanding functions.

I have the following structure of HTML code:

```
<ul class="result">
   <li id="a"></li>
   <li></li> //will be added through a loop depending on input
</ul>
```

And this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //changes are possible when the page has fully loaded
    $('.inp').keyup(function() { //executes keyup function to the field class "inp"
        var inp = $(this).attr('value'); //sets a variable with the value of input from class="inp"
        $.post('ajax/file.php', {inp:inp}, function(data) { //posts that value to file.php as variable inp and executes the function (data) to this 
            $('.result').html(data);  //adds the returned result into HTML content as a first element in the set of class="result" => <li>

            $('.result li').click(function() { //executes click function when clicking li element
                var result_value = $(this).text(); //sets a variable and prepares something as text 
                $('.inp').attr('value', result_value); //fills value attribute of field class "inp" with the variable result_value
                $('.result').html(''); //???
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Now my question is what `$('.result').html('');` does?

Comment: `$('.result').html('');` , set's the html of `.result` `ul` to blank,it remove's everything that is inside of that `ul`

Comment: `$('.result').html(''); ` sets the inner html of the tag with class result to blank, i suppose it would make `<ul> </ul>` from the existing `<ul class="result">
   <li id="a"></li>
   <li></li> //will be added through a loop depending on input
</ul>`. refer http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery .html() property sets the html of the object it is mapped to, it have same behavior like the javascript property .innerHTML.

So here in your scenario $('.result').html(''); will set the html of result class element to null.

```
<ul class="result">
</ul>
```

Secondly, you are using wrong approach in your 'file.php', instead use this code:

```
echo '<li>'.$row["name_1"].'</li>';
echo '<li>'.$row["name_2"].'</li>';
echo '<li>'.$row["name_3"].'</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.result').html('');` sets the html of `.result` to a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.result').html('');` clears the contents of `<ul class="result">`.

http://api.jquery.com/html/